# Android ZBar scanner get barcode format

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, zbar

I am using the the Android ZBar library to scan a barcode and return it. Currently I can retrieve the string and so I am wondering if anyone knows how to return the format of the barcode itself when scanned?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ok got it. It is just calling the getType() method on your Symbol. After you retrieve a Symbol object from the SymbolSet returned by scanner results, just call:

```
yourSymbol.getType();
```

Comment: getType(); just give you int, can we get name of barcode scanned?